# How can I do the dot product of a window and a constant vector in polars?

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I am trying to do calculate a dot product between a window and a static array for all windows in my polars DataFrame and I am struggling to figure out the right way to do this. Anyone here have any hints for me? Here is a quick working example:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

dummy_data = {
    "id_": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "value": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
}
const = np.array([.5, .5])

df_ = pl.DataFrame(dummy_data)
df_ = df_.set_sorted("id_")

# This panics: Cannot apply operation on arrays of different lengths
df_.rolling("id_", period="2i").agg(pl.col("value").dot(pl.lit(const)))

expected = {
    "id_": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "value": [None, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0]
}
```

What I expect is for the following calculations to happen given my example above:

```
np.dot([1.0, 1.0], const)
np.dot([1.0, 2.0], const)
np.dot([2.0, 2.0], const)
etc.
```

Presumably this doesn't work because the first window only has 1 value instead of 2? At least that is what it seems like to me. Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `.agg(pl.col("value").drop_nulls().dot(pl.lit(const)))` runs. The first result is `1.0` which I don't understand. Is this a "bug" I wonder?

Comment: Your code now runs: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/12043 (will be in the next release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving a few answers, and finding one of my own, I wanted to share some benchmarks.

Here are 3 potential solutions to the problem (adjusted slightly to provide a more comprehensive look at the questions by adding a group column):

Data:

```
groups = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        groups.append(i)
dummy_data = {
    "id_": list(range(0, m)) * n,
    "group": groups,
    "value": [random.randint(1, 50) / 100 for _ in range(n*m)]
}
vec = np.array([random.randint(1, 100) / 100 for _ in range(x)])

df_ = pl.DataFrame(dummy_data)
df_ = df_.sort("id_")
```

`rolling_map` courteous of ranc on the polars discord:

```
df_.with_columns(
    pl.col("value").cast(pl.Float32).rolling_map(
        lambda x: sum([x[i]*vec[i] for i in range(len(x))]) , window_size=len(vec)
    ).over("group")
)
```

`rolling` courteous of @DeanMacGregor:

```
(
    df_.lazy()
    .drop('value')
    .join(
        df_.lazy()
        .rolling("id_", by="group", period=f"{len(vec)}i")
        .agg(pl.col("value"))
        .filter(pl.col('value').list.len()==len(vec))
        .with_row_count('i')
        .with_columns(const=pl.Series(vec).implode())
        .explode('value', 'const')
        .group_by('i')
        .agg(
            id_=pl.col('id_').first(),
            group=pl.col("group").first(),
            value=(pl.col('value').cast(pl.Float64)).dot(pl.col('const'))
            )
        .drop('i'),
         on=['id_', "group"], how='left'
    )
).collect()
```

`shift` which is the solution I came up with:

```
df_.lazy().with_columns(
    res = pl.sum_horizontal([pl.col("value").shift(i).over("group") * vec[i] for i in range(len(vec))])
).select(
    "id_",
    pl.when(pl.col("id_") < len(vec))
    .then(None)
    .otherwise(pl.col("res"))
    .alias("res")
).collect()
```

Each provide the exact same answers. Here are the compute times for each on several different sizes of dataset:

```
###################
n=10
m=10
x=2

rolling_map: 826 µs ± 96.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
rolling: 387 µs ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
shift: 160 µs ± 6.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

###################
n=10000
m=10
x=10

rolling_map: 119 ms ± 2.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
rolling: 8.22 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
shift: 24.3 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

###################
n=10
m=10000
x=10

rolling_map: 1.01 s ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
rolling: 25.5 ms ± 318 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
shift: 5.3 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

###################
n=1000
m=1000
x=100

rolling_map: > 60 seconds
rolling: 2.34 s ± 225 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
shift: 731 ms ± 28.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

###################
```

Hopefully these numbers are useful if others need to run some computation similar to this. The correct choice depends on the data being used and the perceived readability of the code.

Comment: oh man seeing how the performance crosses between high n vs high m is making me do my own benchmark with more combinations. Incidentally, you can get random integers from numpy much faster with `np.random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound, n)` than a list comprehension

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I also didn't do any benchmarking as far as maximum memory allocated goes. So that could potentially vary quite a bit between the different implementations as well!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues to contend with. The first, which you've already identified, is that the first window only has 1 value not 2. You can address that by moving the `dot` operation later so that you can do a filter. You're also going to have an issue with how the `const` doesn't broadcast as just `pl.lit(const)` or that `mul` doesn't operate on lists. To account for that you will want to add columns to represent the row index, and your `const`. From there you explode both the `value` and `const` columns. With that done, you don't have any list columns and can do a normal group_by/agg to get the dot to work. To get your desired final result you need to join all of that to the original frame (less the value column that you're replacing).

```
(
    df_
    .drop('value')
    .join(
        df_
        .rolling("id_", period="2i")
        .agg(pl.col("value"))
        .filter(pl.col('value').list.len()==2)
        .with_row_count('i')
        .with_columns(const=pl.Series(const).implode())
        .explode('value', 'const')
        .group_by('i')
        .agg(
            id_=pl.col('id_').first(),
            value=(pl.col('value').cast(pl.Float64)).dot(pl.col('const'))
            )
        .drop('i'),
         on='id_', how='left'
    )
)
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ id_ ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ f64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ null  │
│ 2   ┆ 1.0   │
│ 3   ┆ 1.5   │
│ 4   ┆ 2.0   │
│ 5   ┆ 2.5   │
│ 6   ┆ 3.0   │
│ 7   ┆ 3.5   │
│ 8   ┆ 4.0   │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I fully understand why the following works — it almost seems like a Polars bug? Since your `const` is the same two elements, the following works.

```py
df_.rolling("id_", period="2i", offset="-2i").agg(
    x=pl.when(pl.col("value").len() < 2).then(None).otherwise(pl.col("value").dot(0.5)),
    y=pl.col("value"),
).collect()
```

```
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ id_ ┆ x    ┆ y         │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ [1]       │
│ 2   ┆ 1.0  ┆ [1, 1]    │
│ 3   ┆ 1.5  ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ 4   ┆ 2.0  ┆ [2, 2]    │
│ 5   ┆ 2.5  ┆ [2, 3]    │
│ 6   ┆ 3.0  ┆ [3, 3]    │
│ 7   ┆ 3.5  ┆ [3, 4]    │
│ 8   ┆ 4.0  ┆ [4, 4]    │
└─────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

It seems that somehow `pl.col("value").dot(0.5)` “broadcasts” the `0.5` over `pl.col("value")`. If I replace `0.5` with `pl.Series([0.5, 0.5])`, then I get `PanicException: Cannot apply operation on arrays of different lengths`.

This makes no sense to me, so I assume there is a bug in Polars.